# Datatable selection - inputTextArea doesn't have up-to-date contents

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, page-lifecycle

**Use case**
I have a dialog that contains a datatable and an inputTextArea. The datatable is filled when the user clicks a button. When some (single) row of the datatable is selected, I want the contents of this row to be inserted at the end of the inputTextArea.

[image]

**Problem**
When using the selection attribute of the datatable, I dont have the most recent contents in the inputTextArea. Scenario: I enter "ABC" in my inputTextArea, then click the button, then make my inputTextArea "FFF" and select a row ("dtText") from the datatable. The new contents of the inputTextArea is "ABC dtText" instead of "FFF dtText".

**What I tried**
I tried to add a new listener but I cannot figure out how to bring it in properly so that it is being called before the selection happens. Found nothing on google or in the PF User Guide.
I was hoping the blur event updates my ruleText, but it doesn't happen.

inputTextArea

```
<p:inputTextarea value="#{mrBean.selectedElement.ruleTxt}" id="rt1New" rows="20" cols="100" autoResize="false">
    <f:ajax event="blur" update="duoDlgForm2" />
</p:inputTextarea>
```

datatable

```
<p:dataTable id="qPdt" var="p" value="#{regelBean.queriedParams}" rowKey="#{p}"
selection="#{mrBean.selectedParam}" selectionMode="single">
  <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@form"/>
  <p:column ...
```

java

```
public void setSelectedParam(ParamOrDBParamModel selectedParam) {
    if(selectedParam != null) {
      selectedElement.setRuleTxt(selectedElement.getRuleTxt() + "\n" + selectedParam.getName().trim());
```

How can I work with the most recent text (selectedElement.getRuleTxt) when I am inside the setSelectedParam method?

PF 4.0

**EDIT**: if I try jquery, what do I have to insert into my function

```
$('#qPdt tr').on('click', function() {
  // I reach this point, now what? How to get the contents of a row when I know the type?
  $("#rt1New").append( ?? )
});
```

Comment: The problem section is somehow blurry for me, please try to explain more.. maybe some screenshots or at least name your buttons so we can differentiate between them

Comment: screenshot uploaded. There is only 1 button and it is kinda irrelevant. It just populates the datatable so you can click on rows.

Comment: do you really need ajax requests just to append some text to a textArea ? in other words, why not to consider adding these things by jquery, and when the user for example hit a "save" button, you'd update your model ...

Comment: if you give me a pointer to how, that is also possible. But for me, jquery is more like hacking than proper usage. In this case, any method will do